# both video & audio run as fast as possible - ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg

using this code example (dranger - ffmpeg):

https://github.com/arashafiei/dranger-ffmpeg-tuto/blob/master/tutorial03.c

and dranger tutorial for ffmpeg:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial02.html

The video runs as fast as possible but it makes sense because there is no timer and we just extract the frames as soon as we have them ready. But for some reason, the sound also runs as fast as possible even though he says that it shouldn't.

I'm using mac os x (Maybe that has something to do with it).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
aCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;

> aCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
```